# Учет технического обслуживания оборудования

Tags: база-данных, windows

На работе встал вопрос по автоматизации учета технического обслуживания оборудования. Попросили создать программу, не важно на каком языке, будь то java, c# или что иное. Так же не важно какая база. Лиж бы все работало.

Я в этом не деле не особо компетентен, хотел бы научиться, освоить. Вот и хочу попросить информации, советов, предложений. Я уже разработал примерный поток событий, для программы.

В итоге должно выглядеть примерно так.

Человек запускает программу, есть два вида пользователя, администратор и оператор. Залогинились. Программа выводит некое меню с вариантами выбора. Вся информация хранится в базе. Мы можем добавлять/редактировать информацию, оборудование, сроки проведения технического обслуживания. Через программу админ должен выставить сроки проведения технического обслуживания с выбором приоритета по местонахождению и по типу оборудования. Пользователи могут просмотреть журнал с отображением информации какое оборудование когда должно пройти ТО, либо на каждый день, либо на неделю. Оператор заполняет форму отчета о закрытии смены, что выполнил за смену.

В общем и целом в конечном итоге должно выглядеть так. Вроде понятно описал.

Еще пара вопросов.

На чем проще и удобнее будет сделать программу?

В связке с какой базой данных будет удобнее?

Приложение должно быть десктопным.

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не посмотреть в сторону готовых решений? Например, 1С.

Comment: надо выставлять сроки проведения ТО, автоматом, либо по требованию и по приоритетам.

Comment: @MelCoMe: Да, на платформе 1С это всё легко.

Answer (score 0):

Если все равно, что осваивать, можете попробовать Delphi или C# в связке с СУБД MS SQL Express. Особых проблем в рамках того, что вы описали не возникнет. Кодинга минимум.

Comment: да как уже понял удобнее и легче будет c#+mySql. 
можешь подсказать литературу для изучения?

Comment: Обсуждали [тут](http://hashcode.ru/questions/88709/c-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81-net-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: спасибо. а если конкретно для работы с бд, для моего случая? ведь там многое может быть не столь нужным.